# How to create named pipe acsessible Only on your machin? (VS08 C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, named-pipes, pipe

I have created a program that write video stream to a named pipe on windows, using Visual Studio C++ 2008 . how to be sequre that no one exept programms on this computer can acsess this pipe?

```
  npipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\TestChannel", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,  PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES , 1024, 1024,5000,NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Windows Vista, you can include the `PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS` flag in the `dwPipeMode` parameter. For earlier Windows versions, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150.aspx) suggests using the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter to deny access to the network.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the CreateNamedPipe documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150(VS.85).aspx).
The last parameter is an optional parameter for Security Options.  With that you can specify what users access your pipe. That is the parameter you pass NULL into.